# php COOKIE setcookie malfunction in Chrome, works fine in FF

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

This is my php cookie code,

```
setcookie("city_id", $cityData[0]['city_id'], 2147483647, "/", "localhost");
setcookie("cityname", $cityData[0]['cityname'], 2147483647, "/", "localhost");

echo $_COOKIE['city_id'];
echo $_COOKIE['cityname'];
```

Above code is working fine on FF, but not working in Chrome....
Any suggestions....

Comment: Can you describe the malfunction you are observing? Did you try opening the page in Chrome Incognito mode?

Comment: Is that code as it is shown? I.e. both run in the same request one after the other?

Comment: ON print_r $cityData[0] array, I am getting all the values in it. After setcookie, When I try to access respective cookies it gives error

Comment: @WillSheppard Not working in Incognito

Answer (score 0):

Your setting the timestamp well into the future which could be a problem in FF.

Try setting it a year from today instead - replace `2147483647` with `strtotime('+1 year')`

I doubt you'll still need the cookie to be set in 2038, we will probably all be living on Mars by that point.

Comment: setcookie("city_id", $cityData[0]['city_id'], strtotime('+1 year'), "/", "localhost");
setcookie("cityname", $cityData[0]['cityname'], strtotime('+1 year'), "/", "localhost")....working only in FF

Comment: Remove the last param "localhost" as well

Comment: Removed "localhost" It worked! What should be the domain name on local env?

Comment: You don't need to specify it at all if you want the cookies on the same domain.